# Why measuring execution time of a function call in Javascript leads to inconsistent results?

Tags: javascript, performance, time, performance-testing

I am trying to measure the time it takes to call a (void) function in javascript, but I am getting unexpected results and therefore must be misunderstanding something fundamental.

I have made a toy jsfiddle to illustrate my problem.

https://jsfiddle.net/8hgdzwc5/

```
function f(){
    let iterations = [10, 20, 30, 4000, 50000]
    let times = []
    for(let N of iterations){
        let startTime = performance.now();
        g(N);
        let endTime = performance.now()
        times.push(endTime - startTime)
    }
    console.log(times);
}

function g(N){
    for(let i = 0; i < N; ++i){
        for(let j = 0; j < 4; ++j){
            let x = 0;
          let y = 1;
          let z = x/y;
          let str = "cat";
          let str2 = "cat" + "mouse";
        }
    } 
}
```

I expect the execution times I measure and save in the array 'times' to be increasing, however running the fiddle a few times (I hope this is reproducible), it seems to take **more** time for 4000 iterations than 50000 iterations. Why and how can I measure execution times of functions and make inferences about performance more accurately?

Comment: _"it seems to take less time for 4000 iterations than 50000 iterations"_ Why would you expect something different? What results do you get? I get <= 1 millisecond for each test. How do you compare these values?

Comment: It's hard in JavaScript because the runtime will optimize a function based on how frequently it's called. In your case, the inner loop in your `g()` function does nothing at all, so the optimizer is likely to just throw all the code away.

Comment: I used the larger values and I see the results I would expect: https://jsfiddle.net/hka9edsv/

Comment: @Pointy I don't think the runtime engine/optimizer removes these empty functions. A test case with `5e9` takes 30-40 seconds. I think the values in the question are too small.

Comment: Well it depends on the runtime. There are no function calls in that inner loop and no references (especially modifying references) to anything outside the block. There aren't even object property references. Each iteration of that loop will do exactly the same thing, and there's no output from it; nothing outside the loop is affected, so a decent optimizer can detect that it's essentially a no-op.

Comment: @Pointy Yes, it could. But I tried the Chrome console (not jsfiddle), the Firefox console and Node.js. All 3 apparently don't optimize it. I used `5e8`. Chrome and Node.js took 1.5 s. Firefox took 3.5 s. To be honest, I've never seen a JavaScript optimizer in action. For me it's a myth

Comment: My apologies, I meant it takes **more** time for 4000 iterations instead of 50000 iterations.  So for small values like this comparing times is not feasible?

Comment: You could try to repeat the functions thousands of times to get an average runtime. It's not reliable to compare one single run